# Shows image top of screen

Tags: android, button, view

I want show an image top of screen and bottom of screen some buttons. I write this code but image not shows! How can i solve this problem? If i translate Image to out of RelativeLayout, image shows top of page but view shows like that i seperated bottom page of top page. Why?

another problem with buttons. btn4 button shows a trifle above of another buttons? why?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:background="@drawable/background">

<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">
     <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/smallyelowbar"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/background" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/more_selector"/>
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/contact_selector"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/product_selector"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn4"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/introduce_selector"/>
        </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why have you wrapped your layout inside linearlayout can't you work with RelativeLayout itself

Comment: Thanks for quick reply but i can't understand what you say. Please more expalanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me like your FrameLayout is hiding the ImageView behind it.
Try putting the FrameLayout below the ImageView (either by setting the android:below= attribute on it, or by putting the ImageView over the FrameLayout in the xml).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="#495663"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#DBEAF9" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#DBEAF9" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#DBEAF9" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn4"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#DBEAF9" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Work perfect.**Happy coding!!.**

Answer (score 0):

Try this XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/relative_btngroup"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_btngroup"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn3" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem here is your frameLayout overlaps your image view... thats why its working when you move it out of the relative layout.

try the code below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:background="@drawable/background">

<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="0"
android:layout_gravity="bottom">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/background" />
 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/smallyelowbar"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/more_selector"/>
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/contact_selector"/>
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn3"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/product_selector"/>
    <Button android:id="@+id/btn4"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/introduce_selector"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```